# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails: inserting using perl script

Tags: mysql, sql, perl, foreign-keys

when i try to insert the values from one profile table to other, i find the following error:

**'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails'**

Am i missing something to consider?

As i see its not referring to other table.

```
CREATE TABLE `profile` (
`ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`NAME` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`PARENTID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`TYPE` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`KEY` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
 UNIQUE KEY `PDB_PR_PARENT` (`PARENTID`,`NAME`),
 CONSTRAINT `PROFILE_PARENTID` FOREIGN KEY (`PARENTID`) REFERENCES `profile` (`ID`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

***Update:***

Its first insert, as its migration of data from one db to other db.

I am using the perl script to copy data from profile to PROFILE  table as shown below:

```
$select = $dbh1->prepare("SELECT * FROM profile");
$insert = $dbh2->prepare("INSERT INTO PROFILE VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");

$select->execute;
while ( my @row = $select->fetchrow_array ) {
  $insert->execute(@row);
  print "each row" + @row;
}


**Copy from:** 

CREATE TABLE `profile` (
`ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`NAME` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`PARENTID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`TYPE` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`KEY` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
UNIQUE KEY `PR_PARENT` (`PARENTID`,`NAME`),
CONSTRAINT `PROFILE_PARENTID` FOREIGN KEY (`PARENTID`) REFERENCES           `profile` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

**Copy to table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `PROFILE` (
`ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`NAME` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
`PARENTID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`TYPE` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
`KEY` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
UNIQUE KEY `PR_PARENT` (`PARENTID`,`NAME`),
CONSTRAINT `PROFILE_PARENTID` FOREIGN KEY (`PARENTID`) REFERENCES `PROFILE`
(`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Add the INSERT statement too. Is it the first insert, i.e an empty table?

Comment: Show the INSERT Statement please

Comment: Also, where's the Perl part?

Comment: Do you know what a foreign key is?

Comment: please check the update question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before your loop do

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

And after do

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Comment: i am getting the erro:  Can't locate object method "SET" via package "FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS" (perhaps you forgot to load "FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS"?) at ./perlconnect.sh line 25.

Comment: @ashu: these are mysql statements; in your script you need to do e.g. `$dbh2->do( 'SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;' )`

Answer (score 0):

You have two competing constraints:

- `ParentId` is a reference to the same table.
- `ParentId` is defined to not be `NULL`.

When you insert values into a table, the database engine checks the foreign key constraints.  However, you cannot insert even one row.  Either `ParentId` is `NULL` -- which violates one constraint -- or `ParentId` has a value which cannot be in the table.

Hence, allow `NULL` values for the column.

Comment: it inserted all the rows, except some rows. let me check.